# I'm trying to create a drop down list using flask and html, but there's something wrong. Can someone help me out?

Tags: html, flask, sqlalchemy

```
    {{ form.product.label }}
    <select name="{{ form.product.name }}" id="product">
         {% for product in products %}
              <option value="{{product.name}}">{{product.name}}</option>
         {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

I'm trying to let the user select a value from the names in the product table and store that in a different table, but the drop down list is empty, when it should have had five options in it.

```
  movements = Movement.query.all()
  products = Product.query.all()
  locations = Location.query.all()
  return render_template('movements.html', movements=movements, products=products, locations=locations, form=form)
```

Comment: You haven’t told us what isn’t working. What’s the output you’re getting?

Comment: The drop down list is just empty, when it should have had like five options in it.

Comment: Are you certain that you are receiving anything from your products query?

Comment: When i checked the page source, there was nothing within the select tags, so I don't think I am, but I can't figure out why not because I used the same for loop in another part of the program(to print the values, not to create a list), and that worked.

Comment: have you tried debug it in your route function whether `products` variable is empty or not?

Comment: It's not, I tried simply printing all the product names right after this and it worked, it just doesn't work in the select statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong, the product field in the form was a `StringField`, not a `SelectField`.